# How do I properly model internal memory in my serial flash device?

Tags: simics, dml-lang

I am writing a model for a serial flash device. I wonder how do I best model the internal memory?  I would like the memory size to be configurable by the user since I intend to reuse this model for different serial flashes. It also needs to retain its content upon reset while the rest of the logic is reset.

I tried using a statically allocated character buffer but that is not configurable and seems very inappropriate for such large sizes as my flash model. My flash model is 512 MB.

`saved char flash_image[512 * 1024 * 1024];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this will go into Simics, it is best modeled with two subobjects, both of which are available in Simics Base.

The first is an `image` which stores the actual data, the second is a `ram` which is used to read/write into the image.
Both the `image` and the `ram` are connects using the [`init_as_subobj`](https://github.com/intel/device-modeling-language/wiki/4.-Libraries-and-Built-ins#connect-templates) template which makes Simics automatically create them as *sub-objects*  of the device.
They are placed in a group where we can add an `init` method, which sets default values for the required attributes of the subobjects; in this case the "size" of the image and the "image" of the ram.

The `ram` object also uses the [`map_target`](https://github.com/intel/device-modeling-language/wiki/5.-Standard-Templates#map_target) template, which gives us useful methods for reading and writing into the ram.

```
dml 1.4;

device sample_dev;

import "utility.dml";
import "simics/simulator-api.dml";

group flash is init {
    param size = 0x1000;
    method init() {
        SIM_set_attribute_default(
            ram.obj, "image", SIM_make_attr_object(image.obj));
        SIM_set_attribute_default(
            image.obj, "size", SIM_make_attr_uint64(size));
    }

    connect image is init_as_subobj {
        param classname = "image";
    }

    connect ram is (init_as_subobj, map_target) {
        param classname = "ram";
    }
}


method write_test() {
    try
        flash.ram.write(0, 1, 42);
    catch
        log error: "write failed, it shouldn't!";
}
```

The size of the image is given a default value by a parameter in this example, but it can also be set or overridden by the user when creating the object, by assigning to the attribute `flash.image.size`, e.g. like this:

```
SIM_create_object("sample_dev", "dev", **{"flash.image.size": 0x2000})
```